# SQL Server join using multiple columns

Tags: sql, sql-server, join

I need help with joining two tables in following scenario

```
Table One
Col A
Col B
Col C1
Col C2
Col C3

Table Two
Col C
Col D
```

I need to join [One] with [Two] and get One.A and Two.D as my output.

Here is the join logic:

Join on [One].C1 = [Two].C if no match, I need to join [One].C2 = Two.C again if no match join with [One].C3 = [Two].C

Comment: What's your expectation for multiple rows with the same `One.A` and `Two.D` values?  Do you want to see duplicates?  Have them grouped together?

Comment: @DMason I want them grouped together.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need [`COALESCE()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190349.aspx):

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    COALESCE(One1.A, One2.A, One3.A) AS A,
    D
FROM
    Two
    LEFT JOIN One AS One1 ON
        Two.C = One1.C1
    LEFT JOIN One AS One2 ON
        Two.C = One2.C2
    LEFT JOIN One AS One3 ON
        Two.C = One3.C3;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this query :

```
SELECT 
one.A as oneA,
two.D as twoD
FROM 
One one
INNER JOIN Two two ON one.C1 = two.C 
OR one.C1 = two.C2 
OR one.C3 = two.C;
```

Comment: The problem with this is that you get multiple rows if there are multiple matches, say C1 in one row is the same as C2 in another row.

Comment: I don't think so. See http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/ddc344/1, this is just an example. I know it is not suitable. check out result of that query.

Comment: @unknown Thanks, but your query returns multiple rows when more than one of C1/C2/C3 matches. I want result of first match not multiple rows.

Comment: Do you have SQL Fiddle sample template for query execution ? So that I can try with your data.